# Windows compatible IDE for webdevelopment?

Tags: php, debugging, ide, emmet

I have been searching for the perfect web development IDE for some time now. I first started coding with notepad when all I wrote was HTML. Clearly, that was a relationship not meant to last.

Eventually I discovered Notepad++ and the wonderful syntax highlighting that it does. However, I got frustrated when I started working with server-side code and eventually moved to Netbeans, which I have been using for about a year now.

I enjoy using Netbeans quite a bit. The syntax highlighting is fantastic, the ability to push a button and step through your server side code (once you get your apache server set up properly). And the diff engine on it is fantastic for viewing code side by side. I dislike the learning curve (it seems awfully steep to me), and I've recently wanted to try Zen coding, which I can't do with Netbeans.

So, I am looking for an IDE that allows stepping through server side code, and the ability to install plugins such as zencoding. A good Diff engine would be fantastic (but not a dealbreaker), and making code versioning a bit easier would also be points for it.

Comment: I really like PSPad. It supports zencoding too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some choices:

- [EngInSite](http://www.enginsite.com/php-editor.htm)
- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)
- [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide)
- [phpDesigner](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner.php)
- [Zend Studio](http://zend.com)

Answer (score 2):

While I myself enjoy the simpler things in life such as VI or even notepad++.  Your problem is going to arise when you want to do debugging, as you found it requires an apache plugin.  My best recommendation to you would to look at [zend studio](http://www.zend.com/products/studio/) although it is not free. I've used it with non zend framework apps, and its pretty handy.

Answer (score 2):

As Stijntjhe  mentioned zend studio , if you want free software , use eclipse or eclipse pdt. 
Netbeans also could be good for it.

Comment: Thanks, I will definately give Eclipse a try before paying for anything.

Answer (score 1):

Hi recently i have started the same journey. And my main choices where eclipse with WPT, Aptana en Netbeans. And After a while I returned to Netbeans 7 beta. Which suits me perfectly fine. It is helps me in a robust way which in the end matter the most to me.

Answer (score 1):

The [Zeus IDE](http://www.zeusedit.com/) has support for HTML, CSS and Zen coding.

Answer (score 0):

*Zend Studio for Eclipse*, I used it a while ago when I was still a windows user.
*Html-Kit* is also a good editor but if you're more advanced I prefer the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Dreamweaver is also an excellent Web IDE. It is pricey (if you purchase it).

The best versions are MX2004, CS4, and CS5.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised no one has mentioned UEStudio yet.  It is not free, but is one of the more powerful editors out there.

And I second netbeans as well.